# Final keyword in typescript?

Tags: typescript, final

Is there any way to make a variable available to be assigned only once? Like this

```
interface IFACE {
  a: number;
  final b: number;
}

IFACEConstructor (a: number): IFACE {
  return {a: a, b: 1}
}

test = IFACEConstructor(2);
test.a = 5 // OK
test.b = 2 // Error
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

It will be available since 1.4, you can check the [Announcing TypeScript 1.4 article, "Let/Const" support section](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2015/01/16/announcing-typescript-1-4.aspx):

"TypeScript now supports using ‘let’ and ‘const’ in addition to ‘var’. These currently require the ES6 output mode, but we’re are investigating relaxing this restriction in future versions."

Const should be implemented according to the [article](https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/1622).

You can get TypeScript 1.4 [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/#Download).

#### Update 1

Of course, "const is not the same as final". The question was "Is there any way to make a variable available to be assigned only once?".
So, according this [documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/904):

> Const declarations must have an initializer, unless in ambient context
>
> It is an error to write to a Const

```
const c = 0;
console.log(c); // OK: 0

c = 2; // Error
c++; // Error

{
    const c2 = 0;
    var c2 = 0; // not a redeclaration, as the var is hoisted out, but still a write to c2
}
```

And, for now (Nov, 2015) "const" seems to me the only way, given by typescript out-of-the-box, to accomplish the above task.

For those, who downvoted - if you have another answer, please, share it in this thread with comunity.

#### Update 2: readonly

The [readonly](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/readonly.html) modifier (thanks to @basarat) has been introduced in Typescript 2.0. **You can initialize
them at the point of declaration or in the constructor.**

> You can even declare a class property as readonly. You can initialize
>   them at the point of declaration or in the constructor as shown below:
>
> ```
> class Foo {
>     readonly bar = 1; // OK
>     readonly baz: string;
>     constructor() {
>         this.baz = "hello";  // OK
>     }
> }
> ```

But as said @RReverser in [this thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/6532):

> As usual with all the fresh stuff, you need to use npm i
>   typescript@next to get the latest compiler with experimental features
>   included.

Comment: const is not the same as final. In other words this is not a correct answer

Comment: `const` cannot be used for class members

Comment: @Mihai Răducanu - the "readonly" is just the same as "final". It will be available in Typescript 2.0.

Answer (score 10):

You could use a method decorator and set the writable property of the descriptor object to false.

```
function final(target: Object, key: string | symbol, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
  descriptor.writable = false;
}
```

Then use the decorator in the parent class that contains the final method.

```
class Parent {
  @final
  speak() {
    console.log('Parent speaking');
  }
}
```

If you now extend the Parent class and try to overwrite it's `speak` method you will get an error:

> Error: "speak" is read-only

```
class Child extends Parent {
  // Error: "speak" is read-only
  speak() {
    console.log('Child speaking');
  }
}
```

By using the decorator you have a very descriptive way of marking methods as final.

[Working example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMGYCGAbAFFNAnAcwFMoAuRAeQCMArI6AGkQGsiBPcgZyj1QMQA%20iTmwC2VOBiYATIpwi8ADlDh5yABTxxFRPFDYAROQpjLVASkQBvAFCJEs%20UpV4AdAHdeuKhiKIAvMiYnEQA3DYAvjbREBhonJyI6vhEYFDWdogAAijoGJmcOmjMWJa29vYQCJySRK4YcARYAOTJeKnphUTFfM3m4fZRUTax8YkAwgAWMBjSiEQAHlCp0oltHRn2APRbiACieFpqiABEXcUniDCJ7WjSALQIGGwFRSVlmZXVtfWNLVMzObnZi9fqZIbRXzpBYBRBgIjuRAA2alGwLVzA1E2IA)

**Edit:** As Mark pointed out, this only works when transpiling to ES5 or earlier.

Comment: Hi, I couldn't get this working in the playground but I could very well be missing something. Could you take a look and/or post a working example? Thanks. [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMGYCGAbAFFNAnAcwFMoAuRAeQCMArI6AGkQGsiBPcgZyj1QMQA+iTmwC2VOBiYATIpwi8ADlDh5yABTxxFRPFDYAROQpjLVASkQBvAFCJEs+UpV4AdAHdeuKhiKIAvMiYnEQA3DYAvjbREBhonJyI6vhEYFDWdogAAijoGJmcOmjMWJa29vYQCJySRK4YcARYAOTJeKnphUTFfM3m4fZRUTax8YkAwgAWMBjSiEQAHlCp0oltHRn2APRbiACieFpqiABEXcUniDCJ7WjSALQIGGwFRSVlmZXVtfWNLVMzObnZi9fqZIbRXzpBYBRBgIjuRAA2alGwLVzA1E2IA)

Comment: Hi mark, you need to transpile to ES5 or earlier for the error to be shown [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMGYCGAbAFFNAnAcwFMoAuRAeQCMArI6AGkQGsiBPcgZyj1QMQA+iTmwC2VOBiYATIpwi8ADlDh5yABTxxFRPFDYAROQpjLVASkQBvAFCJEs+UpV4AdAHdeuKhiKIAvMiYnEQA3DYAvjbREBhonJyI6vhEYFDWdogAAijoGJmcOmjMWJa29vYQCJySRK4YcARYAOTJeKnphUTFfM3m4fZRUTax8YkAwgAWMBjSiEQAHlCp0oltHRn2APRbiACieFpqiABEXcUniDCJ7WjSALQIGGwFRSVlmZXVtfWNLVMzObnZi9fqZIbRXzpBYBRBgIjuRAA2alGwLVzA1E2IA) . Sorry i hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 8):

You could use set/get to achieve the result.

```
class Test {

    constructor(public a: number, private _b: number) {}

    get b(): number {
        return this._b;
    }

}

var test = new Test(2, 1);

test.a = 5 //OK
test.b = 2 //Error
```

`test.b` cannot be set because it doesn't have a setter.

TS compiler will not warn you about it, but the browser will throw an error.

Answer (score 5):

There is no final keyword, but you can make use of readonly in the following ways:

### Assign once

```
class IFACE {
    constructor(public a: number, readonly b: number) {}
}

let test: IFACE = new IFACE(1, 34);

 test.a = 5; // OK
// test.b = 2; // Error

console.log(test.a, test.b); // 5 34
```

### Disable overriding

```
class IFACE {
    constructor(public a: number, readonly b: number) {
        // console.log(`b is ${this.b}`);
        this.b = 2; // b is always 2
        // console.log(`b is ${this.b}`);
    }
}

let test: IFACE = new IFACE(1, 34);

test.a = 5;
console.log(test.a, test.b); // 5 2
```

*Not sure if the last one is a bug seeing as you are assigning to a readonly field twice - once in the constructor parameter, and once in the constructor body.*

***Note you can change the last one to this if the double assignment bothers you as much as it did me***:

```
class IFACE {
    a: number;
    readonly b: number = 2;

    constructor(a: number) { this.a = a; }
}
```

Comment: Not a bug, in the constructor the object doesn't exist yet and you're building it, so `readonly` property are writable

Answer (score 3):

this can be also a temp solution

```
class ComponentBase {
// using # pattern, for easy replace when ts final will avaible
    #render(){
        return this;
    }
// just asign your method order to a readonly props or getter
    public readonly render = this.#render;

}
class Component extends ComponentBase {

    public override render(){}; //this make error on method pattern

}

new Component().render();
```

[image]